# controlling width of fixed position elements with width:100%

Tags: html, css

I'm wrestling with two unruly elements - a navigation menu and background bar (kept separate to deal with an opacity issue). Their positions are fixed so they stay visible during scroll. Their widths, which should mimic their parent's, is set with a 100%. Unfortunately, when the window is stretched narrow enough their width extends outside of the parent.

This is a diagram of the html:

```
<html>
<body>
  <content>
    <nav-bar>
    <nav-menu>
    ...
  </content>
</body>
</html>
```

Showing should be easier than describing, so here's a link to the page:
http://www.seanoneill.us/test/index.html

When the browser is stretched beyond the max-width of the content, everything looks fine. When the browser is made narrow, the right end of the nav-bar and nav-menu breaks out of the content width. In other worts, the right edge of "Contact" should be inset from the right edge of the content div by 20px of padding. The best way to see this is to scroll down a big so the menu covers an image and the semi-opaque nav-bar is visible. Then stretch the browser to the max-width of the content and wiggle it back and forth over that threshold.

Can anyone tell me how to keep the nav-bar and -menu inboard of the content div?

I've held off listing any of the css here since there are a handful of elements involved and I have no idea which is the critical one. I'm hoping it's acceptable to just post a link.

Thanks so much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You have `content { min-width:700px }`, and with your `nav` floated right, it will stay there.

If you can remove the `min-width` it will fix itself, or you can move `.nav-manu` outside of the `.content` container and, if you don't wrap it with something else that has `min-width`, it will honor the width of the body/window

Comment: Hey Chris. Thank you. I would like to always keep the right end of the <ul> justified on the right side of the images. When I remove the min-width, the <ul> sticks to the window edge and loses its justification with the image.

Comment: Did you change something since your comment? The nav stays in the same position relative to the image as I view it now.  You do still have a min-width on the body though.  Try spacing your `li`'s with % or using media queries to prevent them from breaking to another line once the screen gets so narrow.